# PHP Pagination Issues

Tags: php, pagination

I seem to be having very annoying problems, I have found a brilliant paginations script however it is doing me nothing but trouble, despite a long set-up time, I got it working to a ok standard, however the script doesn't seem to understand that I want to control "ipp".

```
// PAGINATOR \\

    var $items_per_page;
    var $items_total;
    var $current_page;
    var $num_pages;
    var $mid_range;
    var $low;
    var $limit;
    var $return;
    var $default_ipp = 5;
    var $querystring;
    var $ipp_array;
    var $html;


    function Paginator()
    {
        $this->current_page = 1;
        $this->mid_range = 7;
        $this->ipp_array = array(10,25,50,100,'All');

    }

    function paginate($html)
    {
        if(!isset($_GET['ipp']))
        {
            $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
        } else {
        $this->items_per_page = $_GET['ipp'];
        }
        if($_GET['ipp'] == 'All')
        {
            $this->num_pages = 1;
            $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
        }
        else
        {
            if(!is_numeric($this->items_per_page) OR $this->items_per_page <= 0) $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
            $this->num_pages = ceil($this->items_total/$this->items_per_page);
        }
        if(!isset($_GET['page']) OR $_GET['page'] == '')
        {
            $this->current_page = 1; // must be numeric > 0
        } else {
        $this->current_page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1 ; // must be numeric > 0
        }
        $prev_page = $this->current_page-1;
        $next_page = $this->current_page+1;
        if($_GET)
        {
            $args = explode("&",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
            foreach($args as $arg)
            {
                $keyval = explode("=",$arg);
                if($keyval[0] != "page" And $keyval[0] != "ipp") $this->querystring .= "&" . $arg . $html;
            }
        }
```

**Please note, the above is a snip of the full coding, you can find a full copy of the code at this address: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php**

Okay, so the issue I am having is whatever I pass to the variable ipp through the _GET['ipp'], it seems to totally ignore, however echoing _GET['ipp'] works perfectly fine..

For example, news.php?page=2&ipp=5&id=3. When I change the IPP from 5 to another number, it will totally ignore the fact that I have done that and keep the IPP(Items per page) at 5? I am very confused with the script now, its exactly what I am looking for however just seems to not work my way.

Thank you for any potential helpers, and thanks for having a look.

Best Regards

Comment: Have you tried commenting out this line to see if it is the problem?
`if(!is_numeric($this->items_per_page) OR $this->items_per_page <= 0) $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;`

Comment: Hello Hank, I have indeed commented out that line of code, it did absolutely nothing but cause problems later on in the script!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You realize if you change **$_GET['ipp]** the other values may no longer be relevant, plus who knows what else is going on without running through the code.

My suggestion to solve your problem, some basic debugging:

```
if($_GET) {
  // add some debugging here to see what all the calculated values are
  var_dump(array(
    $this->items_per_page,
    $this->items_total,
    $this->current_page,
    $this->num_pages,
    $this->mid_range,
    $this->low,
    $this->limit,
    $this->return,
    $this->default_ipp,
    $this->querystring,
    $this->ipp_array,
  ));

  // other code already in this block
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. Debugging of these results were as follows.

`array(11) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> int(20) [2]=> int(2) [3]=> float(4) [4]=> int(7) [5]=> NULL [6]=> NULL [7]=> NULL [8]=> int(5) [9]=> string(14) "&id=3#comments" [10]=> NULL }`  :: The script I am using is freely available at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php if you would like to have a look yourself!

Comment: I'm halfway guessing, but it looks like the class may only allow some preset values for items per page per this spurious line `$ipp_array = array(10,25,50,100,'All');`

Comment: This seems to have strangely resolved itself overnight, I was editing code pretty late last night and I seemed to have done something that has made it work as intended, I was last night getting errors where it could not divide by zero, thus because if ipp was not set it was supposed to use the default value(being 5.)

It is now resolved, thanks to everyone who helped I have no idea what happened!